# Convert Map to Json String format

Tags: scala

I´m trying to convert a Map[String, Any] which Any contains as well sometimes a Map[String, Any] and so on, into Json String format.

I´ve found this external library http://json4s.org/ but amaze me that Scala core does not contain a native library to achieve this.

Any idea?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Scala has not built-in feature, but it has amazing sintax... Here you have it, in 8 idiomatic lines:

```
def toJson(query: Any): String = query match {
   case m: Map[String, Any] => s"{${m.map(toJson(_)).mkString(",")}}"
   case t: (String, Any) => s""""${t._1}":${toJson(t._2)}"""
   case ss: Seq[Any] => s"""[${ss.map(toJson(_)).mkString(",")}]"""
   case s: String => s""""$s""""
   case null => "null"
   case _ => query.toString
}
```

Comment: The string line needs to escape special JSON characters. Something like this should do the trick `.replaceAll("\\\\(?![nrbtf\"])","\\\\").replaceAll("\n","\\n").replaceAll("\"","\\\"").replaceAll("\r","\\r").replaceAll("\b", "\\b").replaceAll("\f","\\f").replaceAll("\t","\\t")`

Answer (score 1):

Well JSON is an interchange format (albeit a popular one at present), but then so is XML etc etc. The core library arguably shouldn't concern itself with dealing with a long list of data formats - at least this is what I understand is the reason around limiting such support in Scala core, as in other languages.

There are quite a few libraries that will help you achieve this.

I currently use [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/) for all things JSON in Scala projects, unless I am using Play, in which case it also provides pretty good JSON support. Have a look at Argonaut, you can achieve what you want to quite easily with it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood i thought that you are using your custom implementation for Json which is: `Map[String, Any]`

So here is custom implementation of function that will return String of your map

```
def show(json: Map[String, Any]) : String = {

  def parse(elem: (String, Any)): String = elem match {
    case (a: String, b: Map[String, _]) => "\"" + a + "\"" + ":" + show(b) + ""
    case (a: String, b: Boolean) => "\"" + a + "\"" + ":" + b.toString
    case (a: String, b: Int) => "\"" + a + "\"" + ":" + b.toString
    case (a: String, b: Double) => "\"" + a + "\"" + ":" + b.toString
    case (a: String, b: String) => "\"" + a + "\"" + ":\"" + b + "\""
  }

  val assocs = json.map {
    case(key, value) => parse((key,value))
  }

  "{\n" + assocs.mkString(", \n")+ "}"

}
```

for such Map:

```
val mapJson = Map("root" ->
  Map("field1" -> 1,
      "field2" -> Map("field1" -> true,
      "field2" -> 2.03),
      "field3" -> "Test"))
```

it will print:

```
String = {
"root":{
"field1":1, 
"field2":{
"field1":true, 
"field2":2.03}, 
"field3":"Test"}}
```

Comment: Thanks but not willing to reinvent the wheel, thanks anyway